# Как мне понять на какую именно метку на карте нажал пользователь?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть карта с   маркерами. При нажатии на любую из них должно переходить в другое активити с TextView и Картинками. Для каждого маркера  свой текст и картинки.

> OnMarkerClickListener (устанавливается методом setOnMarkerClickListener) имеет метод onMarkerClick, который дает нам Marker, на который было произведено нажатие. 
>   Куда вставлять этот метод в OnClick или в активити в которое перешли??

Answer (score 1):

В интерфейсе [`OnMarkerClickListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) только один метод:

```
boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker);
```

Вы в нем получаете ссылку на объект типа `Marker`, у которого в свою очередь есть `Id`:

```
public String getId ():
```

> Gets this marker's id. The id will be unique amongst all Markers on a map.

Помимо `Id` можно получить его `title`.

Эти `Id` и `title` можно через `Intent` передать в другое `Activity`, чтобы оно отобразило соответствующую картинку

Comment: Этот OnMarkerClickListener должен быть реализован в исходной Activity которая отображает карту. Из него из метода onMarkerClick можно запускать Activity, которое должно отображать TextView с картинками, передавая ему в качестве параметров Intent-а Id и/или title нажатого маркера